# Why is Python's "sorted()" slower than "copy, then .sort()"

Tags: python, performance, sorting, optimization

Here is the code I ran:

```
import timeit

print timeit.Timer('''a = sorted(x)''', '''x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]''').timeit(number = 1000)
print timeit.Timer('''a=x[:];a.sort()''', '''x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]''').timeit(number = 1000)
```

and here are the results:

```
0.00259663215837
0.00207390190177
```

**I would like to know why using .sort() is consistently faster than sorted() even though both are copying lists?**

Note: I am running Python 2.7 on an 2.53Ghz i5 with Win7

Comment: Recommend you try this multiple times in a row with much larger lists for rigor

Comment: @AndrewGorcester I buy the larger list suggestion, but why more times?  Is 1000 not enough for reasonable statistical accuracy?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with the timeit module and had just realized it was being repeated 1000 times at the same time that you replied.  That should be plenty of repetitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference you are looking at is miniscule, and completely goes away for longer lists.  Simply adding `* 1000` to the definition of `x` gives the following results on my machine:

```
2.74775004387
2.7489669323
```

My best guess for the reason that `sorted()` was slightly slower for you is that `sorted()` needs to use some generic code that can copy *any* iterable to a list, while copying the list directly can make the assumption that the source is also a list.  The sorting code used by CPython is actually the same for `list.sort()` and `sorted()`, so that's not what is causing the difference.

**Edit**: The [source code of the current development version of `sorted()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/11a08c377a3b/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1848) does the moral equivalent of

```
a = list(x)
a.sort()
```

and indeed, using this code instead of your second version eliminates any significant speed differences for any list sizes.

Comment: [results on my machine support your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11547854/4279).

Comment: Yup - `list.sort` can work with a known size, and swap elements within that size, `sorted()` has to work with unknown sizes and generic iterables, and thus may have to allocate memory as it builds (possibly forcing a memcpy if not contig.), but this should be minimal as you've stated. Copying a list is fairly simple as that's just a simple malloc/memcpy op (and creation of a new PyObject*)

Answer (score 1):

In support of [@Sven Marnach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11547729/4279):

There is a small difference for small lists:

```
$ python2.7 -mtimeit -s "x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]; s=sorted" "a=s(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 usec per loop

$ python2.7 -mtimeit -s "x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]" "a=x[:];a.sort()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 usec per loop
```

The difference goes away with `* 1000` (larger lists):

```
$ python2.7 -mtimeit -s "x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]*1000; s=sorted" "a=s(x)"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.42 msec per loop

$ python2.7 -mtimeit -s "x = [(2, 'bla'), (4, 'boo'), (3, 4), (1, 2) , (0, 1), (4, 3), (2, 1) , (0, 0)]*1000" "a=x[:];a.sort()"
100 loops, best of 3: 3.48 msec per loop
```