# Python lists: why is .sort() much faster than sorted()?

Tags: python, sorting

I measure the time it takes to sort a list of 10 million entries:

```
import time

a = range(10000000, 0, -1)
b = range(10000000, 0, -1)

start = time.time()
a.sort()
end = time.time()
print end - start

start = time.time()
sorted(b)
end = time.time()
print end - start
```

The output I get:

```
0.272000074387
0.468999862671
```

The reason might be because `sorted` is more generic, **but this is not consistent with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547588/why-is-pythons-sorted-slower-than-copy-then-sort)
where the difference became miniscule in large lists**. What is causing the huge difference?

I am using python 2.7.3 32 bit on 32 bit windows 7, Q6600 processor.

Comment: If you will read my question you will see I gave a link to it, and my results are not consistent so how is it a duplicate?

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all. I vote to reopen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sort` version operates on the list in-place, but `sorted` makes a copy of the list. When the actual sorting is so easy (Timsort detects that the whole list is one big backwards run and reverses it), the creation of the copy can have a significant runtime impact.

Comment: You are right. when I use more complex list the difference becomes much smaller. Wasn't aware of Timsort - thought it was just Quicksort...