# Most efficient way to combine information from each row of groups in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, performance

Consider the following code. The purpose of this code is to go through a `groupby`, and combine information from each of the rows in the groups and save it into a `pd.Series`.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"], "B" : ["x", "y", "z", "w", "t"] })
groups = df.groupby("A")
strings = groups["B"].apply(lambda x : "".join(sorted(x.values + " ")))
strings2 = groups["B"].apply(lambda x : str(len(np.unique(x))) + "hello")
print(strings)
print(strings2)
```

Outputs

```
a    t x y 
b      w z 
Name: B, dtype: object
A
a    3hello
b    2hello
Name: B, dtype: object
```

For example, the first apply statement in the code sample above is to concatenate the rows of column `"B"` into one string, with spaces added.

I would like to make this code as fast as possible and to be able to scale it to the setting of multiple millions of rows.

This is the most efficient way I've been able to find so far to do this task, but I think part of the problem is that `.apply` is not vectorised in pandas, so applying this to each group is a very slow process (typically, there are more than 300,000 groups). Each group only has size 2 or 3.

Alternatively I could try skipping the `groupby` and doing this directly on the original `DataFrame`. A solution that works this way would also be appreciated.

In summary, I would like a way to rewrite the above code that achieves the same thing, but as fast and space efficient as possible (scalable to extremely large datasets).

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution for `strings2` I found was:

```
def cast_multiple_apply_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(pd.unique).map(len).map(repr) + "hello"
```

For `strings2` the OP's method is quite slow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

_rng = np.random.default_rng(123)

def setup(N):
    x = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(x)
    y = ["x", "y", "z", "w", "t"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(y)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x, "B": y})

    groups = df.groupby("A")
    return [groups]


def original_poster_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(lambda x: str(len(np.unique(x))) + "hello")


def bracula_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(lambda x: f"{len(pd.unique(x))}hello")


def len_multiple_apply_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(pd.unique).map(len).astype("string") + "hello"


def npsize_multiple_apply_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(pd.unique).map(np.size).astype("string") + "hello"


def set_multiple_apply_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(set).map(len).astype("string") + "hello"


def cast_multiple_apply_approach(dfg):
    return dfg["B"].apply(pd.unique).map(len).map(repr) + "hello"


approaches = [
    original_poster_approach,
    bracula_approach,
    len_multiple_apply_approach,
    npsize_multiple_apply_approach,
    set_multiple_apply_approach,
    cast_multiple_apply_approach,
]
for approach in approaches[1:]:
    data = setup(100)
    assert (approach(*data) == approaches[0](*data)).all()


run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [
        1000,
        3000,
        5000,
        10000,
        30000,
        100_000,
    ],  # ,300_000,500_000,1_000_000],#3_000_000,5_000_000,10_000_000],
    setup=setup,
    title="Performance Comparison",
    number_of_repetitions=1,
)
```

[image]

Therefore I excluded it from running on a large sample:

[image]

For `strings`, I was surprised to find that:

- OP's method is actually really hard to beat
- Sorting beforehand is terrible

I could improve a little on OP's solution by using native `pd.Series.str.join` over the joining in pure Python:

```
def pandas_str_accessor_approach(df):
    return df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(sorted).str.join(" ")
```

```
def setup(N):
    x = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(x)
    y = ["x", "y", "z", "w", "t"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(y)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x, "B": y})
    return [df]


def original_poster_approach(df):
    return df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x.values + " ")))


def pandas_str_accessor_approach(df):
    return df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(sorted).str.join(" ")


def sort_first_approach(df):
    df.sort_values(by=["B"], inplace=True)
    strings = df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(" ".join)
    return strings


approaches = [
    original_poster_approach,
    pandas_str_accessor_approach,
    sort_first_approach,
]

run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [
        1000,
        3000,
        5000,
        10000,
        30000,
        100_000,
        300_000,
        500_000,
        1_000_000,
        3_000_000,
    ],  # 5_000_000,10_000_000],
    setup=setup,
    title="Performance Comparison",
    number_of_repetitions=1,
)
```

[image]

[image]

Profiling code used:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N,
                               teardown=lambda: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5, title='Performance Comparison',data_name='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}

    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                approach_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: approach(*data), number=number_of_repetitions)
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Take a look at my update, you're going to like this one.

Comment: Funny thing, on my machine my solution is faster than anything else. Is build related?

Comment: I thought your edit was really funny, since i edited your `string` to `string2` as well xD i'm running Python 3.11.0 on MacBook Pro M1 2020

Comment: Yeah, that was a nice touch \m/ However, I was actually talking about how a small function like `sorted` causes such a high overhead when called so many times. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm replicating your answer now. I have an almost irrational dislike of `apply`/`lambda` ...

Comment: But I already upvoted your answer, you improved it a lot :)

Comment: i just tried out ` dfg["B"].nunique().map(repr) + "hello"` and it's worse than `.apply(pd.unique).map(len)` ??????

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: There is a `nunique` method on groupby objects which gives number of unique values per group, but it's slower than `.apply(pd.unique).map(len)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254483/discussion-between-bracula-and-sebastian-wozny).

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create a reproducible dataframe
_rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
x = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"] * 10_000_000
_rng.shuffle(x)
y = ["x", "y", "z", "w", "t"] * 10_000_000
_rng.shuffle(y)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : x, "B" : y})

groups = df.groupby("A") 

def strings2_old(dfg):
    return dfg['B'].apply(lambda x : str(len(np.unique(x))) + "hello")

def strings2_new(dfg):
    return dfg['B'].apply(lambda x : f"{len(pd.unique(x))}hello")
```

```py
%timeit strings2_old(groups)
>>> 20.7 s ± 82.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%timeit strings2_new(groups)
>>> 1.9 s ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Every other implementation of your first method I tried including what [Andrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) suggested is worse than yours. Sorting is prohibitively expensive regardless of the scale unless it's a sorting network.

---

UPD

Reading [Sebastian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665986/6326375) amazing answer got me down the rabbit hole of optimisations. Can we actually do better? Apparently, we can: [Python lists: why is .sort() much faster than sorted()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645469/python-lists-why-is-sort-much-faster-than-sorted)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

_rng = np.random.default_rng(123)

def setup(N):
    x = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(x)
    y = ["x", "y", "z", "w", "t"] * N
    _rng.shuffle(y)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x, "B": y})
    return [df]

def pandas_str_accessor_approach(df):
    return df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(sorted).str.join(" ")

def pandas_str_accessor_approach2(df):
    def transform(_x):
        _x = _x.tolist()
        _x.sort()
        return _x
    return df.groupby("A")["B"].apply(lambda x: transform(x)).str.join(' ')

approaches = [
    pandas_str_accessor_approach,
    pandas_str_accessor_approach2
]

run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [
        1_000,
        3_000,
        5_000,
        10_000,
        30_000,
        100_000,
        300_000,
        500_000,
        1_000_000,
        3_000_000,
        5_000_000,
        10_000_000],
    setup=setup,
    title="Performance Comparison",
    number_of_repetitions=5,
)
```

[image: Linear scale]
[image: Log scale]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can sort the dataframe by column `B` before grouping and then just apply `str.join`:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['B'])
strings = df.groupby("A")['B'].apply(' '.join)

print(strings)
```

Prints:

```
A
a    t x y
b      w z
Name: B, dtype: object
```